# How does one become a god?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, religions-and-deities

How does one become a deity? I read *Deities and Demigods*, but some things are either not explained or not mentioned at all.

- Do you have to get a blessing from a god with 20+ divinity?
- Can you achieve ascendancy with a lot of worshipers? (Let's say a million.)
- Can you ascend if you kill a god?
- Is there a ritual to become a god?
- Any other means of becoming a god?

Comment: I'm hoping that an answer might take into account PC progression to god, e.g., BECMI(mmortals), [D&D Immortals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_Immortals_Rules)

Comment: This is another one of those great 'out of context' questions to see when scanning the question list.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Follow the Rule of Cool

Not a RAW answer, but if your dm agrees with you, there's nothing wrong with you taking epic actions to take on a divine portfolio.

For instance:

- Murdering a god, see [Bhaal](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Bhaal), [Bane](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Bane) and [Myrkul](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Myrkul)
- Achieving the simultaneous prayer of a million worshippers (See the [Doctor's Crystal Dragon Jesus moment](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/DoctorWhoNSS3E12TheSoundOfDrums), here's the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=CnAIMmfuJEo#t=388s) for anyone that hasn't watched it.)
- Sacrificing a world to seal the abyss

Just don't expect it to be easy.

Comment: Not having watched any Doctor Who, that TvTropes link doesn't seem to explain any kind of godhood; could you give a better example?

Comment: I will probably go with the combination of the above. Killing a god while being praised by a million worshippers or something like that.

Comment: @ioanwigmore, As someone who _does_ watch DW, I find it an odd choice, as well. The Doctor doesn't ascend to godhood in _The Sound of the Drums_, rather, he utilizes the low-level latent psychic abilities of all the humans on Earth (linked together by the Master's subliminal messaging satellite network) to reverse the effects of the Master's laser screwdriver which had advanced his body's age beyond helpfulness.

Comment: In the Greyhawk campaign setting, this has been explicitly addressed, as one of the major NPCs used a certain method in order to gain godhood.

Comment: Could one Wish to become a god?

Answer (score 24):

Well, here is how my group did it, without the DM's approval (until the last moment of course, he could probably have said "NO.")

- We all had fake names, for some reasons (mainly being paranoid, but also because we had betrayed every king in the world at least once), and the DM had forgotten that the names we were using were not our real names
- We started saying we wanted to make the world's biggest magic school / magic guild. We wrote a school chart, including bullet point 8: "On 8th day of 8th month, all followers should participate to a cult in the name of [Real name of PJ1], God of [Domains he wanted to get], etc.."
- We then went and beat the tarrasque (hint: she can be drowned), in order to build fame. Then we recruited people, converted other schools and guilds, beat people who disagreed, until we had several millions of people following us.
- We conducted the cult, the DM asked "Wait, who are those gods by the way?"
- We showed him our character sheets, especially the "Name" part. According to his own words, he was "impressed and horrified at the same time".
- He thought it was cool, and wanted to go that way, so gave us a Rank 0.
- Profit.

Again, it depends entirely of the DM's willingness to go with it, but this is a way of achieving it.

Comment: Yeah, my idea is similar, only none of the players would know what I am doing so I need DMs approval.

Comment: Well, I could definitely have pulled that one by myself, but I thought it was more fun if everyone became a god :) Be careful though, as a DM I might approve with one of my PC doing that kind of thing, but he would become a NPC soon after.

Comment: Knowing my DM he won't make him a NPC. More likely everyone would get divinity (through plot) and then we would start slaying gods xD

Answer (score 18):

### The DM should decide based on the campaign world and PC history:

I'd say that this is mainly a DM decision, and depending on the type of gods in the world you are playing, might end with converting the PC to a NPC.

For example...

I once played a wizard that worshipped the god of knowledge.  When they read some *older than the gods* scrolls the god got to know about some ancient knowledge and disappeared.  As a consequence I lost my priest spells.

Some days later, we finished successfully the campaign.  We were playing in a very heroic way and my character died in the last minute. The dragon we awoke (who was a lot more powerful than the gods) resurrected my PC to take the place of the lost god of knowledge.  This was a reward from the DM for good role playing during all the campaign, and was a good and reasonable solution for the world we were playing.

Of course I lost the character anyway, but the next time we were playing within the same world it was nice to know that the god of Knowledge was my previous character.

So in summary, I think it should be something that

- fits the world
- fits the past of the character
- happens as a consequence of some very relevant success on the part of the PC
- DM and Players agree on it.

Comment: Since there are three players in training, DM and me I think that only the two of us should agree (because of the character history). Also I am playing a used-to-be-god whose worshipers were are slayed and he suffered full memory and ability loss. Now, he doesn't know he is a god (but he think he is his worshiper). There is a little problem of divinity, because he would be overpowered with any level of divinity but I would let DM sort that out.

Answer (score 13):

## Take an [Epic Destiny Feat](http://web.archive.org/web/20090602124646/http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/drfe/20080428&pf=true)

More specifically, the one titled Demigod. These replace your first four epic feats with a single one, which grows in power up through level 30.

> ...As you travel through this epic destiny, you gain a small following of worshipers, which grows with each level until you become a full-fledged deity, and enhances your inherent divine power.
>
> Note that the demigod epic destiny does not use the demigod traits outlined in Deities and Demigods. This is to keep the demigod's abilities more in line with the rest of the party, and for simplicity's sake...

The capstone ability at level thirty --

> When you reach the end of your destiny quest, you become a true deity (if a minor one). Perhaps you create your own divine domain and portfolio, or perhaps a deity you had a close connection with gives you a piece of his power in respect for your incredible service.

Answer (score 10):

There are rules for increasing one’s Divine Rank in *Deities and Demigods*. You have to have Divine Rank 0 to do that, though. There are very few mechanical ways to achieve that (the Dragon Ascendant epic prestige class from *Dragons Of Faerûn*, for example), so mostly you just have to rely on some plot development; see Simon Gill’s answer for ideas on that.

Answer (score 6):

At the risk of having a DMG thrown at my head... there's always [Pun-Pun](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=6637.0). Divine rank can be acquired through (ab)use of Manipulate Form and *Ice Assassin*.

Not recommended as anything other than a theoretical exercise.

Comment: A bit complicated as there are three new players. I'll go with slaying gods and gaining followers.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways. For instance:

- One can be elevated to divinity by another god, like [Red Knight](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Knight); or
- Kill a god and usurp his power, like [Bane](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Bane); or
- A dragon can become a quasi-deity through the [Draconomicon](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Draconomicon%3a_The_Book_of_Dragons) class Dispassionate Watcher Of Chronepsis (the DM could allow them to receive level 0 divinity); or
- Maybe through extremely powerful magic.

In the end, is up to the DM to decide whether a player can become a god or not.

Comment: Worth noting that in Forgotten Realms, [Karsus' avatar](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Karsus'_avatar) is supposedly the only spell that ever allowed the caster to become a god. Two caveats: it would last only for the spell's duration and Mystra restricted the use of magic afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There's alot of ways to do this "by the book" but.. it is completely up to the DM wether or not you can become a god/deity.. My DM could do a scenario where we travel on the road and i get stung by a bee and become the god of bee's for all he cares.. ANYTHING can turn you into a god if it suits the DM.. Pretty simple..

Answer (score -5):

RAW, there's no way to do it. RAW is chock full of ascended mortals, of course, but the whole point is that they got there by doing things that can't be done. That they're not in the rules could be called a rule in and of itself: take something impossible and do it anyway.

Comment: Simply inaccurate; there are a handful of RAW methods for achieving Divine Rank. *Dragons Of Faerûn*’s dragon ascendant epic prestige class, for example, makes you a “quasi-deity,” which by *Deities and Demigods* rules means you have Divine Rank 0 (and *Deities and Demigods* provides rules for increasing it from there). There is also the already-linked-to Demigod epic destiny feat, and a really cheap trick involving *ice assassin*. And, of course, there’s Pun-pun.

Comment: @KRyan Where do I find "ice assassin"? What book is it in?