# How can a low level player attain demon prince hood?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Myself and one of my players who I frequently let CO-DM for me were wondering if there were any rules in D&D 3.5 for a low level player becoming a demon prince.

The demon prince should give powers similar to a Balor or Abraxas The Unfathomable, but appropriate for a lower-level party.

These rules dont have to be core and can be home-brew.

To clarify atm the party is around level 6 to 7 and will be most likely getting to level 12 in the next session.(They are fighting in a tournament with one on one opponents so they get all the xp to themselves).

I intend for the player to have gained something similer to a divine spark but have it instead be a demon lord spark.  It would essentially be a level 0 spark where he would maybe gain a template or a prestige class called demon lord, and then work his way to demon prince at level 20 of that class.  Along the way he would gaining power in the class.  (With the party is around 6 to 7 now, there is only one player that will have this chance to become that class.  The prize from winning the tournament will be the chance to become that class/prestige class).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site!  I would suggest taking a look at the [faq] and [tour], there's a lot of useful information in there about the kinds of questions that fit best with this site.  This question is pretty unclear as it stands.  I would suggest pulling out the specific problem you're trying to solve, and avoid any extraneous detail.  It sounds like the core question is "Are there rules for a low-level character to become a god or demon prince?"  If so, you should edit your question to focus on that specific topic, so we can more easily understand what you want.

Comment: The most important details that I can see that are either missing or unclear: The level of the party, the specific kind of prince/godhood you're trying to use, and what your DMing structure is.  If you are co-DM, do you both have to agree on this, or does one of you have authorial control?  Also, I'd suggest removing the lines asking for "suggestions".  Terms like "Any suggestions?" are red flags here, and typically indicate a kind of question that doesn't work well in our format.

Comment: Ah ok sorry im a bit new here and i thought a little clarification on the situation would help.I will change it.

Comment: This is a lot closer to a solid question.  The one thing still unclear to me is what you mean by "demon prince".  Do you have specific rules in mind, or do you just like the flavour of someone being a demon prince, and you're looking for rules to go along with that?  I'm asking for more details here because it's pretty clear what "divine rank 0" means, but I don't know of any equivalent kind of template for a demon prince.

Comment: I made some edits.  Feel free to revert them or edit the question further if I misunderstood what you're trying to get at.  I think you're probably going to get some more questions from other people about what it is you want for your demon prince request, but this is a lot more clear and specific than before.

Comment: Ah alright thanks for the help sorry i have trouble explaining things in short sentences and genraly add a small or large paragraph behind it.

Comment: Is the question *What powers should a low-level PC god possess?* or is it *How can a low-level PC achieve godhood?*

Comment: Its a little of both can a low level pc achive god hood/Demon Lord Hood and if so what powers should they have.

Comment: This question is not appropriate to this site; it is looking for idea generation and discussion. Since this site does Q&A, and not discussion, it isn’t going to work here. May I suggest you try [one of the discussion forums we recommend](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4563)?

Comment: Attaining godhood for any character is answered [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/18610/8610). I don't think specifying *low-level* merits a separate question as low-level options can be gleaned from the answers. The demon prince question, however, remains unique. I'd like to see this question be about *just* becoming a demon prince (maybe *lord* instead?), which is, I think, something one of the experts on the planes might be able to answer with examples and a history-of-D&D lesson.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan Thanks for the suggestion i have edited the question to what you suggested since the former part of it was answered.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the intention to make this similar to a prestige class, entered at a level as you stated in the revised question.  I performed an edit to try and smooth out the flow of your new edit and to fix a few spelling errors.  If my edit has changed the meaning of your question, please edit  that again to fix any error I may have made by accident.

Comment: Alright thank you and no it didn't change the premise of the question.Also sorry for all the spelling errors i a dyslexic so its a big problem for me.